# Adding contents of Session and Application at end of each page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2003

A long time ago, I came across a handy little utility that, if turned on, would append the contents of Session and Application to the end of each page.

I'm trying to maintain a very old VS 2003 application and something like this would really be helpful as the app makes extensive use of globals via the Session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable Tracing:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" requestLimit="40" pageOutput="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx

If you want a specific page (not all pages):

```
<%@ Page [...] Trace="true" %>
```